# Unexpected behavior for numpy self division

Tags: python, numpy, division

```
def f(x):
    x=x/5.
    return x
def g(x):
    x/=5.
    return x

x_var = np.arange(5,dtype=np.double)
f(x_var)
print x_var
g(x_var)
print x_var

Output:
[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
[ 0.   0.2  0.4  0.6  0.8]
```

This behavior is a little bit strange to me, I always thought x/=5. was equivalent to x=x/5. . But clearly the g(x) function does not create a new reference with /= operation.  Could anyone offer an explanation for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I always thought x/=5. was equivalent to x=x/5

It is, unless the class overrides the `__idiv__` operator, like `numpy.ndarray` does.
`numpy.ndarray` overrides it to modify the array in-place, which is good because it avoids creating a new copy of the array, when copying is not required.  As you can guess, it also overrides the rest of the `__i*__` operators.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I couldn't find the documentation which would lead me to expect this behavior.

Comment: This is not a numpy problem, it is a passing objects by reference problem. The default implementation of all `__i*__` is to do the operation in place if possible, read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__). You will have the same problem passing a Python list to a function that did `def f(a): a *= 3; return a`, it would modify the original object you called it with, not simply return a modified copy.

Comment: Thanks, this  was the documentation reference I was looking for.  So it should perform the operation in-place if possible.  If the __i*__ is not available it will default to the normal __*__ operation.

Answer (score 3):

Python's in-place operators allow the operation to *modify* the object on the left side of the equation rather than creating a new one. You'll see the same behavior with `list`s and other built-in mutable types:

```
x = []
y = x
x += [1]
print y   # prints [1] because x still refers to the same object as y
x = x + [2]
print x   # prints [1, 2] for obvious reasons
print y   # prints [1] again because x has been rebound to a new list
          # while y still refers to the original one
```

So this is expected behavior.

When dealing with immutable types, of course, a new object is created, because the existing one can't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

> I always thought x/=5. was equivalent to x=x/5.

It is not. When you do `x=x/5.`, you're in fact performing **two** separate operations below the hood:

```
temporary = x/5.
x = temporary
```

whereas when you're using the `/=` operator, you're explicitly asking Python to modify your object `x` in place, without the creation of a temporary object. As mentioned in other answers, the `/` operator calls the `__div__` method of your object (if any), while `/=` calls its `__idiv__` method.

The in-place modification is quite useful if the object you're modifying is large: no need to create an as-large temporary object. However, it can bite you if you're not careful. In particular, it's usually not that great an idea to have a function modify its input parameters without warning...