# when plotting autocorrelation function plot getting UFuncTypeError

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, statistics

when plotting autocorrelation function plot gettingUFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'divide' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int32') the error happens after the comment # Plot the autocorrelation function for X and Y. do I need to convert trace x and y to float?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the probability matrix
p = np.array([[10/66, 15/66, 3/66], [20/66, 12/66, 0], [6/66, 0, 0]])

# Initialize starting values for X and Y
x = 0
y = 0

# Create arrays to store trace plots
trace_x = []
trace_y = []

# Run 12,000 iterations of Gibbs sampling (with 2,000 burn-in)
for i in range(12000):
    # Sample a new value for X given the current value of Y
    py = np.sum(p[y])
    x = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], p=p[y] / py)
    # Sample a new value for Y given the current value of X
    px = np.sum(p[:, x])
    y = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], p=p[:, x] / px)
    # Append the new values to the trace plots after the burn-in period
    if i >= 2000:
        trace_x.append(x)
        trace_y.append(y)

# Plot the autocorrelation function for X and Y
plt.acorr(trace_x, maxlags=50)
plt.title('Autocorrelation plot for X')
plt.xlabel('Lag')
plt.ylabel('Autocorrelation')
plt.show()

plt.acorr(trace_y, maxlags=50)
plt.title('Autocorrelation plot for Y')
plt.xlabel('Lag')
plt.ylabel('Autocorrelation')
plt.show()
```

Comment: both `x` and `y` are lists of integers, choice from 0,1,2.  So as `arrays` they would be `dtype` `int`,  Full traceback may show why `acorr` is trying to do in place divide (nomalization?)

Comment: @hpaulj, the default `normed` is True, hence the `/=` inside `downcasts it to integer inside _axes.py`,  not sure why they chose to do in-place in the xcorr function. I think it was not intended, hence put a pull request for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look into the traceback reveals that the error is due to the lines

```py
    if normed:
        correls /= np.sqrt(np.dot(x, x) * np.dot(y, y))
```

inside the `matplotlib` source code at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py.

The error appears due to the prevention of automatic upcasting within the `numpy` library when using in-place operations. This has been beautifully explained in an answer by SO user: [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31987859/3896008). Now, to answer the OP's question, we need to steer clear of the in-place operation.

So, for the OP's specific problem, there are three solutions:

*Solution 1.* If normalised values are not needed, the `normed=False` can be passed in the `plt.acorr` function as an argument as shown below:

```py
    plt.acorr(trace_x, maxlags=50, normed=False)
```

Output:

[image]

*Solution 2.* If normalised values are needed, cast the input to float first:

```py
plt.acorr(np.array(trace_x, dtype=float), maxlags=50)
```

Output:

[image]

*Solution 3.* The fix can be applied inside the matplotlib's code itself. To change the in-place operator to regular assignment as:

```py
correls = correls / np.sqrt(np.dot(x, x) * np.dot(y, y))
```

Output (Same as solution 2):

[image]

I put a pull request for this to matplotlib [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/25832) and referred to the OP's question. I will update the answer if my pull-request is approved.

**EDIT:**
The pull request has been approved. The `acorr` function works as expected even when using a list or numpy array with all integers.

Comment: or `plt.acorr(np.array(trace_x, dtype=float), ...)`

Comment: It is far better to ask numpy to make the data a float array directly rather than adding a float and relying on its upcasting rules.  You get the desired effect (passing a float type array into Matplotlib) without modifying your data!